# Limit Python function scope to local variables only

Tags: python, function, scope, global-variables

Is there a way to limit function so that it would only have access to local variable and passed arguments?

For example, consider this code

```
a = 1
def my_fun(x):
    print(x)
    print(a)
my_fun(2)
```

Normally the output will be

```
2
1
```

However, I want to limit `my_fun` to local scope so that `print(x)` would work but throw an error on `print(a)`. Is that possible?

Comment: [`Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) -- The Zen of Python

Comment: If you want to restrict who can access `a`, you can re-structure your code thinking about the scope of each variable/function... or you can use a hack. If you decide to restructure, you can limit the scope by using modules/class or namespace. For this simple example, namespace will do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel like I should preface this with: **Do not actually do this.**

You (sort of) can with functions, but you will also disable calls to all other global methods and variables, which I do not imagine you would like to do.

You can use the following decorator to have the function act like there are no variables in the global namespace:

```
import types
noglobal = lambda f: types.FunctionType(f.__code__, {})
```

And then call your function:

```
a = 1
@noglobal
def my_fun(x):
    print(x)
    print(a)
my_fun(2)
```

However this actually results in a different error than you want, it results in:

> NameError: name 'print' is not defined

By not allowing globals to be used, you cannot use `print()` either.

Now, you could pass in the functions that you want to use as parameters, which would allow you to use them inside the function, but this is not a good approach and it is much better to just keep your globals clean.

```
a = 1
@noglobal
def my_fun(x, p):
    p(x)
    p(a)
my_fun(2, print)
```

Output:

```
2
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Answer (score 3):

Nope.  The scoping rules are part of a language's basic definition.  To change this, you'd have to alter the compiler to exclude items higher on the context stack, but still within the user space.  You obviously don't want to limit *all* symbols outside the function's context, as you've used one in your example: the external function `print`.  :-)